# Get pending Message count from AWS SQS queue Using nodeJs

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am a new be to AWS. I have a doubt is there any way to get number of messages(total count of messages) pending in AWS-SQS queue using NodeJs. If there is any way to get the count please help friends to solve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you Tuan Anh Tran

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({
 region: 'REGION'
});

// Create the SQS service object
var sqs = new AWS.SQS({
  apiVersion: '2012-11-05'
});

// Set params
var params = {
 QueueUrl: queueURL,
 AttributeNames : ['ApproximateNumberOfMessages'],
};

sqs.getQueueAttributes(queParams, function(err, data){
   if (err) {
          console.log("Error", err);
        } else {
          console.log(data);
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

It's field `ApproximateNumberOfMessages` in get Queue attributes https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/get-queue-attributes.html